# Custom Debounce Code Not Working

Tags: arduino-uno, debounce

It's my custom debounce code

It keeps the led on by flipping the required threshold value when triggered after the led has turned on to keep the led in a high state and vice verse triggered again, the comments on the code explain it in more detail.

```
/*
 * This code is my custom debounce code, I made this but this isn't working as planned, 
 * see the thing is that it turns on when I hold the button and if I release it, 
 * it starts to flickers and then gradually turn off, what is wrong with my code ? 
 * I can't see it.
 */

const int ledPin = 13; // led connected to pin 13
const int PushButton = 2; // a pushbutton connected to pin 2
int switcher = HIGH; // the switcher changes it's value, we require this later
int dilay = 1; // controls the delay
unsigned long lastTrigger = 0; // records the last time the led was turned on

void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT); // sets ledpin as output
  pinMode(PushButton, INPUT); // sets pushbutton pin as input
}

void loop() {
  int pushButtonState = digitalRead(PushButton); // stores the value of the pin each time the loop begins agian

  if((millis() - lastTrigger) >= dilay){ // my custom debounce code
    if(pushButtonState == switcher){ //  this is the trick, when the pushbutton pin is high it's equal to the switcher value
      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH); // it turns on the led 
      int switcher = LOW; // now the switcher value will be low now the pushbutton pin value will also be low keeping the led on
    }else{
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW); // now if the led is on and pushbutton is high, then it will not be equal to the switcher because we had changed it in the previous statement 
      int switcher = HIGH; // now the switcher is high and the pushbutton value low, switcher isn't equal to pushbutton so there by keeping the ledpin as low

    }

    if(pushButtonState == 1){ // if pushbutton is high
      int lastTrigger = millis(); // then  lastTrigger equals to the current time
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: how is the button wired? do you have a pulldown resistor?

Comment: the button is a switch which connects the 5v pin and pin 2, and no i don't use a pull down resistor

Comment: without pulldown, the pin free floats between LOW and HIGH when disconnected from 5V

Answer (score 1):

Change `int switcher = LOW/HIGH` to just `switcher = LOW/HIGH`.

Otherwise you are redefining the variable, and will make it a local variable, and not change the global variable with the same name (as you are expecting).

Comment: PS you code isn't actually doing any debouncing. It negates it a bit by only polling the input pin every 1 ms. But in some switches [bouncing can take up to 6ms](http://www.ganssle.com/debouncing.htm).

Comment: now with the change you suggested, it makes the led blink now